# A Coin Flip Problem Reconsidered

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In an earlier [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316296/a-coin-flip-problem/316334#316334), I asked:

"Suppose I have $n$ fair coins, and I mark one of them for identification. Next I flip the n coins without looking. My friend, who is looking on, now informs me that there were at least $k$ heads flipped.

What is the probability that my marked coin was heads?"

To that, @Łukasz Grad answered:

$$P(X_1 = 1| S \ge k) = \frac{\sum_{i = k}^{n} \binom{n-1}{i-1}}{\sum_{i=k}^{n}\binom{n}{i}}$$

But suppose the question was instead:

$P(S \ge k | X_1 = 1)$

and

$P(S \ge k | X_1 = 0)$

How does the answer change?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can combine the [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/316296/a-coin-flip-problem/316334#316334) of Łukasz Grad and [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem). For instance,

$$P(S\geq k|X_1=1)=\frac{P(X_1=1|S\geq k)\cdot P(S\geq k)}{P(X_1=1)}$$

Obviously $P(S\geq k)=\sum\limits_{i=k}^{n}\binom{n}{i} \cdot 0.5^i\cdot 0.5^{n-i}$ and $P(X_1=1)=0.5$

Comment: I think you mean $P(S \ge k)$ and ${n \choose i}$

Comment: Yes. Good catch. Thanks

Comment: @Callculus, should $P(S>k)$ in the numerator not be $P(S>=k)$

Comment: @user120911 Sure. I have forgotten it at my first edit.

Answer (score 1):

For $X_1 = 1$, just take the probability of $n-1$ coins landing on at least $k-1$ heads:
$$
\begin{split}
P(S \ge k \mid X_1 = 1) &= \sum_{i=k-1}^{n-1} \text{Binomial}(i; n-1, 1/2) \\
&= 0.5^{n-1} \sum_{i=k-1}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose i}.
\end{split}
$$

Similarly, for $X_1 = 0$, get the probability of $n-1$ coins landing on at least $k$ heads.

Comment: your answer and Callculus' answer seem to be different in the summation. Why do you subtract 1 from n and 1 from k?

Comment: Is you answer for X = 0 ?

Comment: @user120911 Actually, if you work out callculus' answer, you'll find that it turns out to be the same as mine

Comment: "For `$X_1 = 1$`, take the probability of `$n-1$` coins landing on at least `$k-1$` heads"

That makes intuitive sense. It seems like a general answer. Does it not also hold even if coins are not fair? I guess in that case we must keep track of the marked coin, by removing it and computing the probability of the other `$n-1$` coins landing on at least `$k-1$` heads". Here we would be dealing with the Poisson Binomial. Do you agree with that @Bridgeburner?